# Find the minimum and maximum values while a certain condition is occuring using sql

Tags: sql

I have a dataset coming from a sensor on a truck which tells me when the truck is running, the truck is idle, and when the truck has been turned off. Unfortunately, when the truck spits out its data, each individual event is not an individual row in the SQL table, but over multiple rows. I am trying to find the start time and end time for each event where the truck is 'off' (value = 0) to calculate the availability statistics for that truck each day. The table looks like this:

Truck Data

[image]

I can get the minimum and maximum times overall for the data set, but not sure how to do it for each event on a continuous basis.

Comment: You will need to have a cursor and iterate over the results to get the consecutive values with the same value (status)

Comment: please tag the database you are using. also post the expected result.

Comment: Agreed with the above comment. Depending on what database you are using, there are completely different and incompatible tools available to solve this problem.

Comment: please post expected result and btw i don't think cursor is the best solution

Comment: A CTE or subquery to find the pairs (base, next) of timestamp and minimum timestamp greater than the base timestamp, grouped by Value, used in a recursive CTE using a self-join of that output to group all sequences of cases where the next timestamp equals a base timestamp for the same value should produce a view with columns of value, earliest timestamp, and latest timestamp for each contiguous sequence of Values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach much simpler than the one in my comment on the original post.  The thing that all members of each group have in common is the minimum greater timestamp for a different value.  So:

```
select
    min(tr.tstamp) as start_time,
    max(tr.tstamp) as end_time
from (
    select
        t1.value,
        t1.tstamp,
        min(t2.tstamp) as next_value_tstamp
    from
        truck as t1,
        truck as t2
    where
        t2.tstamp > t1.tstamp
        and t2.value <> t1.value
    group by
        t1.value,
        t1.tstamp
    ) as tr
where
    value = 0
group by
    next_value_tstamp;
```

will give you a set of paired start and end times for each sequence where value = 0.  The base data table is assumed to be named "truck".  The code uses "tstamp" instead of "timestamp" because using keywords for column names is asking for trouble.